# How to generate PDF files for Oracle Reports from command prompt?

Tags: report, oracle12c, weblogic12c, oraclereports

Compile script is as below -

```
rwrun report=E:\Reports\Reports12\Report_name.rdf userid=id/pwd@db DESFORMAT=pdf  
      DESTYPE=FILE DESNAME=E:\Reports\WebsiteReports\Report_name.pdf replace=Y batch=yes
```

I have tried to write the above script in .bat file and even tried executing from Command prompt (Oracle 12c- Weblogic).

PDF aren't generated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: the parameter `replace` is unfamiliar to me. Can you run without `replace` again ? You can even remove `batch` parameter.

Comment: Still can not generate PDF after removing `replace` and `batch` - `rwrun report=E:\Reports\Reports12\Report_name.rdf userid=id/pwd@db DESFORMAT=pdf  
      DESTYPE=FILE DESNAME=E:\Reports\WebsiteReports\Report_name.pdf`

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: Scripts run ok in command prompt with no errors.

Comment: I am able to generate PDF using the below code -

Answer (score 0):

I am able to generate PDF using the below code -

filename.bat -

`cd D:\Oracle\Weblogic\user_projects\domains\prod_domain\reports\bin d: rwrun report=E:\Reports\Reports12\imposter.rdf userid=id/pwd@dbname DESFORMAT=pdf  DESTYPE=FILE DESNAME=E:\Reports\WebsiteReports\PDFs_for_KI_upload\imposter.pdf batch=yes rwrun report=E:\Reports\Reports12\countystats_arnp_emp.rdf userid=id/pwd@dbname DESFORMAT=pdf  DESTYPE=FILE DESNAME=E:\Reports\WebsiteReports\PDFs_for_KI_upload\arnpempl.pdf batch=yes`

But, it only run and generates PDF for first report and never goes to second report.